# Override of "select" builtin

Tags: bash, function, alias, keyword, undefined-behavior

Recently I tried to override three common commands:

- sleep
- wait
- select

The first one (`sleep`) is commonly an external bin (`/bin/sleep` in my Debian 10).
The second one (`wait`) is a builtin (You can check it with `command -v wait`).
The third one (`select`) is also a builtin.

I will write some examples in order to reproduce what works and what not, please be patient.

There are no problems in overriding `sleep` and `wait`, I just added somewhere in my code the following:

```
sleep() {
  echo using custom sleep
}
wait() {
  echo using custom wait
}
```

Things change when I try to override `select`.

In particular, if I try to create a simple function as above, I get errors as the parser (?) thinks I am trying to use the command rather than create a new function.

You can reproduce the error with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
select() {
  echo using custom select
}
```

This is avoidable using the notation `function select() {`.

If I'm using an interactive shell I can solve the issue with an **alias**; steps to reproduce:

```
_select() { echo using custom select;}
alias select='_select'
select
```

**BUT** this solution doesn't work if I use files.

Let's try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is the actual script
. lib.sh
select
```

... and:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this is where I declare the function select
_select() {
  echo using custom select
}
alias select='_select'
```

If I run `script` which in turn source `lib.sh` I will get an error when I try to call my alias.

This is the first time, for me, that an alias is a "second choice" after a builtin.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is this an actual "bug"?

Obviusly, a workaround would be rename the function in something else.

Comment: Btw. `select` is a keyword and no builtin.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you for this distinction, I searched for differences between keywords and builtins and it actually does solve my doubt. In particular, I found that keywords are scanned early in bash parsing and that's the reason. Also, using `type select` is much better than `command -v select` to determine this. If you like, make an actual answer, I will flag it as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` man page in section `ALIASES`:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set 
>   using shopt (see the description of `shopt` under `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` below).

Either add

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

before the first use of `select` or add `-i` to your shebang

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

for an interactive shell.